# hardware install, care to explain?

Tags: hardware

I have tried to active post release ATI AMD, but it seem don't work, anyone you know how to do this? please thanks http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/854/screenshotfrom201206141.png/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
```

If that doesn't worked try doing these steps

- `sudo apt-get --purge remove fglrx`
- `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates`

Then if there aren't errors try rebooting.

P.S. If you prefeer the packages are also in Ubuntu Software Center so you can install them from it.

[fglrx](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/fglrx) [image: Install fglrx]

Comment: yep, sure you are.

Comment: i have a other question, do you know command, like this, but about nvdia?

Comment: i think that you have to install: 
nvidia-current, nvidia-settings, nvidia-current-updates, nvidia-settings-updates

Comment: Thanks again! because i have own laptop, AMD, and i will plan to install my older sister's laptop, so anyway, thanks!

Comment: No problem, i'm here to help ^^